# Edge Browser Issue : Width : fit-content is not honoured while in chrome its working fine

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

Size of the first level header (in grey background) is growing in size as per the size of the largest flex item in case of edge browser. While in case of chrome it is honouring fit-content width and is being rendered accordingly.

HTML:

```
<section id = 'tileContainer' class = 'tileContainer'>
      <div id = 'leftSideContent' class = 'leftSideContent'> 
        <div id = 'firstLevelHeader' class = 'firstLevelHeader'>
          First Level Header
        </div>
        <div id = 'secondLevelHeader' class = 'secondLevelHeader'>
          Second level header has a got a very long text inside of it
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id = 'rightSideContent' class = 'rightSideContent'>
        X
      </div>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
.tileContainer{
    margin: 25px;
    height: 120px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: solid 0.2px #d2d3d3;

    .leftSideContent {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        min-width: 0;

        .firstLevelHeader{
            background-color: #8a8a8a;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            height: 20px;
            align-content: center;
            width: fit-content;
        }

        .secondLevelHeader {
            height: 20px;
        }
    }

    .rightSideContent{
        justify-content: center;
        width: 50px;
    }
}
```

Behavior in edge:

[image]

Behavior in Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Do you really need a `width` value? Have you tried without it?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava - Without width value first level header grows as per the largest element. I need the behavior as in case of chrome(as per attached snapshot). Without having width value it behaves same in chrome as it in edge(according to attached for edge browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it seems that you're using Edge Legacy. `width: fit-content` is not supported by Edge Legacy but supported by Edge Chromium, you could check it on [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=fit-content).

One alternative is to use `display: table`, which has the same effect as `width: fit-content`:

```css
.tileContainer {
  margin: 25px;
  height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: solid 0.2px #d2d3d3;
}

.tileContainer .leftSideContent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 0;
}

.tileContainer .leftSideContent .firstLevelHeader {
  background-color: #8a8a8a;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  align-content: center;
  width: fit-content;
  display: table;  /*add this line*/
}

.tileContainer .leftSideContent .secondLevelHeader {
  height: 20px;
}

.tileContainer .rightSideContent {
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section id='tileContainer' class='tileContainer'>
  <div id='leftSideContent' class='leftSideContent'>
    <div id='firstLevelHeader' class='firstLevelHeader'>
      First Level Header
    </div>
    <div id='secondLevelHeader' class='secondLevelHeader'>
      Second level header has a got a very long text inside of it
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id='rightSideContent' class='rightSideContent'>
    X
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

`width: fit-content` is not supported on Edge. [you can find out more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#Browser_compatibility)

you can use `display: table` as an alternative. works the same way.